# Can't allocate anything from my project - static library (using XCTests)

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, unit-testing, xctest

When i try tests like

```
@interface My_Tests : XCTestCase
- (void)testExample {
     XCTAssertTrue(@YES, @"has to be passed");
}
```

Everything is working fine. However when i try such pattern:

```
 #import "NSString+Additions.h"
 //...
 - (void)testNameValidation {
      NSString *string = @"Harry";
      XCTAssertTrue([string stringIsValid], @"Name validation error");
 }
```

I get:

```
file:///Users/username/project/ProjectTests/ProjectTest.m: test failure: 
-[Project_test testNameValidation] failed: (([string stringIsValid]) is true) 
failed: throwing "-[__NSCFConstantString stringIsValid]: unrecognized selector
sent to instance 0x2f58ae8" - Name validation error
```

I can also just do something like this:

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
//...
- (void)testSomething {
    MyViewController *a = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    XCTAssertTrue(@YES, @"Impossible!");
}
```

I get 2 errors (first and last line):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyViewController", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in MyTest.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone explain me what am I doing wrong..? I can't do anything with my classes. It may be worth adding that i'm trying to test my custom static library and files included in it. I'm using CocoaPods and I've set environment basing on Kiwi description (only to be able to use CocoaPods files in my tests, I was also wondering whether to use Kiwi or XCTests).

PS. This is my first try with unit tests of any type, so please forgive eventual noobish question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit tests aren't linked against the static library.

Add the library to the "Link Binary with Libraries" section of the build phases for the test target.

Comment: Can you tell in more details something like where is this particular configuration..?

Comment: Yes, I've noticed. This seems to solve this issue, but now i get 31 other errors, eg

`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
<list here>
"_kUTTypePNG", referenced from:
      -[MyCache setImage:forKey:] in libNameKit.a(MyCache.o)` Do i have to do anything else? My pods is linked there.

Comment: Ok, i resolved the second one: have to add also all frameworks required by library. Thank you for your help!